# Screen sharing is impossible since upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Since I upgraded to 20.04, the screen sharing is not possible anymore. The **button does not even appear into the gnome control panel**, and whenever I try to through any tool, either I get weird behaviour from the tool (or the navigator), or I only manage to share a black screen with my mouse being the only visible thing on it. When I look at the "sharing" options in the panel, I am only proposed to share medias ...

I tried to dig into several forums, remore/reinstall the gnoime control panel.

The tools with which I've tried are numerous (skype for linux, 8x8, jitsi, webex ...), each time with different navigators, if possible (not for skype, obviously) => firefox or chrome.

I ended-up to the conclusion some kind of setup parameter was broken during the migration, any idea on what I should check to get it back ?

Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use X11, it should work out of the box.

If you use wayland you have to use pipewire 0.3 to be able to share your screen.
Unfortunately, only 0.2 is present on 20.04, so you have to backport it from hirsute and compile `xdg-desktop-portal` and `mutter` with it.

To build packages more easily you can use the image provided by [screencast-pipewire-focal](https://github.com/damienrg/screencast-pipewire-focal) that already contains patches.